# Android app, app keeps stopping error after rename

Tags: android, react-native

I have recently renamed my `react-native` app using [react native rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename)

My app works fine in my emulator, but when installed on device, I get the error 'app keeps stopping' as soon as I click the launch icon.

I've checked all the occurrances of my app name and it seems ok. How can I debug the error?

Comment: Logcat can give you some hints...

Comment: It doesn't show errors or anything weird.